# Extract data from fusion charts to excel

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fusioncharts

I am using selenium to automate the application which has fusion charts in it.
Is there any method so that i can export the chart data to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link was helpful for me to get out of the problem
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?JavaScript/API/Overview.html